# Limited connectivity on Windows Vista but Internet still works?

Tags: windows-vista, networking, internet, home-networking, internet-connection

I am running Windows Vista Home Premium SP2. I have my PC connected to a Belkin Router via an Ethernet cable. My network icon in the system tray shows an exclamation mark in a yellow triangle. When I rollover this network icon, it tells me "Access: Limited Connectivity", as shown here:

[image]

When I look at my Network and Sharing Center it shows the same thing, that I am not connected to the Internet:

[image]

The strange thing is that I *do* have access to the Internet; I am posting this question despite this issue.

Does anyone know what could be happening? Or how I would find out what the issue is?

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that you are also connected to any other networks? Virtual networks included.

A good start point is doing a quick ipconfig /all in cmd. If it does not show a default gateway then Windows does not show a full connect. Also is this a persistent issue? (ie have you tried a reboot, i am assuming yes)